# Can't load FOT toolbox on Scilab 6.1.0

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04, scilab

I recently installed the Scilab 6.1.0 on my Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine on my windows pc. I am able to use the editor but cannot seem to load the Fossee Optimisation Toolbox. It installs successfully but shows the following error when restarting and trying to load the toolbox. I have already tried reinstalling Scilab and ubuntu. Can someone tell me how to resolve this?
***atomsLoad: An error occurred while loading 'FOT-0.4':
exec: error on line #61: "link: The shared archive was not loaded: libquadmath.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"***[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAEfW.png)

Comment: Can you try to install gfortran (`sudo apt-get install gfortran`) ?

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet Thank you so much it's loading now. Can you tell me why this worked?

Comment: See the detailed answer (BTW you can validate it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOT is built using gfortran, and the missing library is one of its libraries. Scilab uses also gfortran and is including the corresponding libraries. But there is likely a version number mismatch, i.e. FOT has been built with a more recent version of gfortran. Installing a system wide gfortran with `sudo apt-get install gfortran` will probably install the version you need.